Where is the workbench.web.main.css gone after updating to 1.95 from 1.93?
just noticed the ./src/vs/workbenchworkbench.web.main.css is gone after the update.
I usually added custom content there for loading additional fonts.
Does anyone know how to add custom fonts now when running VSCode web based?

#229915 reworked and removed workbench / css files

